# How to avoid type safety warning with generic interfaces and Class.forName

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code which is forking fine:

```
private <X extends SomeInterface<MyImplementation>> void test(String fqcn)
{
    Class<X> c = (Class<X>)Class.forName(fqcn).asSubclass(SomeInterface.class);
    ...
}
```

However, I get a type safety warning

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends SomeInterface> to Class<X>
```

and wondering how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prove that this casting is safe and would succeed. You're performing casting of `Class<?>` (of *unknown type*) returned by `Class.forName()` into the `Class<X>` (of something), the compiler can't verify if what you're doing is correct.

The only thing you can do is to suppress the warning by placing annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method on the problematic statement:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <X extends SomeInterface<MyImplementation>> void test(String fqcn) {
    Class<X> c = (Class<X>)Class.forName(fqcn).asSubclass(SomeInterface.class);
    ...
}
```

Or

```
private <X extends SomeInterface<MyImplementation>> void test(String fqcn) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<X> c = (Class<X>)Class.forName(fqcn).asSubclass(SomeInterface.class);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the reflection java.lang.Class "api docs" for forName method, it should be wrapped in  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and java.lang.ClassCastException.
The correct Exception(s) should remove that warning.

**use isInstance(theCreatedClassReference) from java.lang.Class**

don't want to try without code and compiler , take too long for me.

isInstance() returns a boolean and is the correct to use for Class.forName(stringnametoload) check alike the *instanceof* operator
when creating a Class check its constructed reference in an if test
the multi argument Class.forName allows class loading usage designation of whether it is "initialized".

*sorry about the botched code attempt.*

If you are actually making a usable reference then maybe check with instanceof but the actions DO require the exception wrappers (not a bad idea when they can be interfaces and other types in one).

I can only presume from your code you are loading a class that will be returned "something like (and as the byte code compiler sees it)" a <T> type by genericsthat could be any type, so the runtime would have no idea what resource of byte code would be loaded.
Not knowing what the T type will be is extremely dangerous.
If you flag Class.forName with initialize false using its multi argument method version you can load an uninstantiated class as a test to see that the dynamic resource is true for the compiled code before it is able to be loaded live.
It would then tested the resource class loaded.

Comment: *"The correct Exception(s) should remove that warning"* - That's **WRONG**. It feels like you're confusing a [compiler warning](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/terms/0080/) with a [*compilation error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation_error). Warnings prevent the code from being compiled, but errors do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP knows how to deal with checked exceptions. An unhandled checked exception will cause a *compilation error*, not a *warning*. Try it out yourself - surround the `Class.forName()` call with a `try/catch` or add a `throws` clause specifying `ClassNotFoundException` to the method signature in order to make the code compile. And face the warning listed in the question. There's no relation between an *unchecked cast* and handling checked exceptions.

Comment: Alexander Ivanchenko possibly, but my memory those warnings and errors for what is being done in dynamically creating a class means you forget what trying to debug is without good information. To dynamically create a usable class by that system Class.forName is hell in itself and top of the pops with ClassLoader control. Personally i'd just feed the exception blocks 
 relevent onto that one to know it all went as it had, because if anything went wrong !!!!!!!!...... To genuinely understand "only quite enough" of why and how to do dynamic class creation is reaching achievement in the language.

Comment: None of that alters the fact that you answered the wrong question. Just accept it.